# PCL complains no member functions

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
My system details: Arch Linux, ROS melodic. I have installed the ROS system using `yay`.

I am building a library that is dependent on PCL library.

Part of the code that I am using is;

```
  pointcloud_pub_ =
      nh_.advertise<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>>("time_horizon_pointcloud", 1, true);
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr msg(new PointCloudXYZRGB);
  msg->header.frame_id = world_frame_id_;
  msg->is_dense = true;
  msg->height = 1;
  msg->width = points_with_id.size();
  msg->points.resize(points_with_id.size());
  ros::Time ros_timestamp;
  ros_timestamp.fromNSec(timestamp);
  pcl_conversions::toPCL(ros_timestamp, msg->header.stamp);
  // pointcloud_pub_.publish(msg);
```

The commented line is the one which is causing the following error (i.e, if not commented out, it causes the following error and if commented out no error is reported.).

```
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/message_traits.h:125:14: error: ‘const class std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> >’ has no member named ‘__getMD5Sum’
  125 |     return m.__getMD5Sum().c_str();

/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/serialization.h:144:14: error: ‘const class std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> >’ has no member named ‘serializationLength’
  144 |     return t.serializationLength();
      |            ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/serialization.h:127:7: error: ‘const class std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> >’ has no member named ‘serialize’
  127 |     t.serialize(stream.getData(), 0);
```

I am not quite sure how to circumvent this error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369946/pcl-complains-no-member-functions/) by [anonymous25787](https://answers.ros.org/users/25787/anonymous25787/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2021-01-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr` is not a `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2`. You cannot directly publish a `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr`. You need to convert it to a `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` first.

See [Publishing point clouds](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros#Publishing_point_clouds) on `wiki/pcl_ros`.

---

Edit:

> But based on [this tutorial](https://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Overview#CA-12e6086fb209b846509558aa8797d543f6a46cfd_11) I am allowed to publish. Although I am able to get rid of the error if the `msg` is of the type `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>` rather than `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr`.

Apparently there are overloads for `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>` which perform the conversion for you.

In that case you should pass the pointed-to, instead of the smart pointer itself.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous25787](https://answers.ros.org/users/25787/anonymous25787/) on 2021-01-21**:
But based on [this tutorial](https://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Overview#CA-12e6086fb209b846509558aa8797d543f6a46cfd_11) I am allowed to publish. Although I am able to get rid of the error if the `msg` is of the type `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>` rather than `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr`.